# how to check what is inside javascript object

Tags: javascript

Is there any method or way to check what is inside a JavaScript object. something like `print_r` in PHP?

Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Firebug for Firefox or Developer Tools for Google Chrome/Safari to inspect your objects. It's the best way to do it in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Use this custom function or [JSON.stringify(obj);](http://www.json.org/js.html)

```
  /**
   * Gets the string representation of the specified object. This method is
   * used for debugging
   * @param {Object} Object to convert to string
   * @return {String} The string representation of the object
   */
  var toObjectSource = function(obj)   {
     if(obj === null)   {
        return "[null]";
     }
     if(obj === undefined) {
        return "[undefined]";
     }

     var str = "[";
     var member = null;
     for(var each in obj)   {
        try   {
           member = obj[each];
           str += each + "=" + member + ", ";
        }catch(err) {
           alert(err);
        }
     }
     return str + "]";
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Javascript objects are esentially maps of key/value pairs.  You can access members through both dot notation (e.g. `myObject.someProp`), or even through index notation (`myObject["someProp"]`).  The use of the latter will probably help you:

```
function print(obj) {
    for (var i in obj)
        console.log(i + " - " + obj[i]);
    }
}
```

Run that through Firebug and see what you get :)

Answer (score 3):

If you use Mozilla Firefox, you can use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/). To see what your variable or object is, do it like code below (for example, I use JSON variable)

```
var yourObject = {test: 'this is just a test'};
console.log(yourObject);
```

After you install Firebug, run your html file that contains this javascript and choose Console tab in Firebug. You will see the result there. Hope this helps you. :)

Answer (score 3):

Best trick for me:

```
console.dir(yourobject);
```

See it live in your chrome dev tools. You can pass in any object to find out what's inside of it a swell. Very helpful

Comment: Pretty nice, and works fine at the browser. But I couldn't use it on my computer terminal, on my React-Native-CLI to be more specific. :/

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following object:

```
var x = {
  property1: 'value1',
  property2: 'value2',
  property3: 'value3',
  method1: function () {
    return 0;
  },
  method2: function () {
    return 0;
  }
};
```

Then doing:

```
for (var prop in x) {
  console.log(prop);
}
```

Outputs:

```
property1
property2
property3
method1
method2
```

You may want to use the [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method to ensure that you do not get properties from the object's prototype chain:

```
for (var prop in x) {
  if (x.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    console.log(prop);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com). Its a plug-in for [Mozilla Firefox](http://getfirefox.com).

In your source file, write: `console.log(yourObjectGoesHere);` and go to the "console" tab in FireBug... Killer object discovery, presented in an easy-to-grasp tree-format.